# How to add recaptcha v3 to a php contact form?

Tags: php, recaptcha

Excuse me very much if what I'm about to ask seems stupid. I'm a php novice, so I'm trying to learn.

I was inspired by a tutorial to create a php contact form that works superbly well.

But I want to add reCaptcha. So I tried to do this.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['recaptcha_response']))) {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

/*------------------- reCaptcha added -----------------------*/

// Build POST request:
        $recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $recaptcha_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

        // Make and decode POST request:
        $recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
        $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

        // Take action based on the score returned:
        if ($recaptcha->score >= 0.7) {
            // Verified - send email
        } else {
            // Not verified - show form error
        }

/*---------------- End reCaptacha --------------------*/

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "hello@example.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

But it returns the error below.

> stdClass Object ( [success] => [error-codes] => Array ( [0] => missing-input-response ) )

But the email is still being sent. So the error has no impact on the form. 
Can you please tell me where the problem is? You will really help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Hi @KiranManiya my question was simple, however. Anyway, I modified it. I hope it's better for you. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

score >= 0.5) {
        // Verified - send email
    } else {
        // Not verified - show form error
    }

} ?>

Comment: Hi @hhussayyn I don't understand. You want me to just close the php tag? I opened a single php tag for the entire code. If I close it at this level, where do I put the rest of the code?